# "We next consider" vs "We consider next"

Tags: word-order, sentence-patterns

In a technical scientific paper, should I write

> "We next consider an example of ..."

or

> "We consider next an example of ..."

or

> "Next we consider an example of ..."

Comment: I will edit my post to include your comment. Thank you.

Comment: how does your first example sentence start? Do you have more examples after this one?

Comment: @depperm You mean: "We next consider the OP's additional example".  To OP: without more context, in a technical paper I'd go for the first version.

Comment: 1. Natural order.  2. Also grammatical  3. Could do with a comma after *next* for readability. All are fine. Each has a different focus point. Essentially, *next* is parenthetical here.

Comment: @Kris That's interesting. What would be the difference in focus point in each case?

Comment: In the natural order, "next" is not emphasized, "example" gets focus. In the last order, "next" takes focus.

Comment: @Kris: Re: which word gets the focus: That's odd, I was going to say the reverse.

Comment: @ruakh I read the first example as "_[Next we consider] **an example of**_" ... we've (presumably) just considered one _example_, and are moving on to the next _example_. It is the _examples_ that are important; the "moving on" (_next we consider_) is by-the-by.

Comment: (1) and (2) do not sound natural in conversation (but neither does this 'consider'). They are more formal than (3) and (4) (We consider an example of ... next.) and hence might be considered more appropriate in a paper. I'd say there's little to choose between (1) and (2) (even in emphasis).